# Docker Conditional build image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have to execute the same script to two `docker` images.

My `Dockerfile` are:

```
FROM centos:6
...
```

and

```
FROM centos:7
...
```

Is it possibile to have a single file and pass a parameter, something like:

```
FROM centos:MYPARAMS
```

and during the build somethings like that:

```
docker build --no-cache MYPARAMS=6  .
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my knowledge, this is not possible with Docker.

The alternative solution is to use a **Dockerfile "template"**, and then parse it using the template library of your choice. (Or even using `sed` command)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33353438/1497139 for an implementation of this approach

Answer (score 32):

Just to put this in right context, it is now (since May 2017) possible to achieve this with pure docker since 17.05 (https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31352)

Dockerfile should look like (yes, commands in this order):

```
ARG APP_VERSION
ARG GIT_VERSION
FROM app:$APP_VERSION-$GIT_VERSION
```

Then build is invoked with

```
docker build --build-arg APP_VERSION=1 --build-arg GIT_VERSION=c351dae2 .
```

Docker will try to base the build on image `app:1-c351dae2`

Helped me immensely to reduce logic around building images.

Comment: Just a word of warning that is described in the doc ( https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact ) : If you need to use your argument after the FROM, you will need to redeclare it after the FROM

Answer (score 2):

At https://github.com/BITPlan/docker-stackoverflowanswers/tree/master/33351864
you'll find a bash script "build" that works the way you want.

```sh
wf@mars:~/source/docker/docker-stackoverflowanswers/33351864>./build -v 6
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584 kB
Step 0 : FROM centos:6
6: Pulling from library/centos
fa5be2806d4c: Pull complete 
ebdbe10e9b33: Downloading 4.854 MB/66.39 MB
...

wf@mars:~/source/docker/docker-stackoverflowanswers/33351864>./build -v 7
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584 kB
Step 0 : FROM centos:7
```

The essential part is the "here" document used:

```sh
#
# parameterized dockerfile
#
dockerfile() {
  local l_version="$1"
cat << EOF > Dockerfile
FROM centos:$l_version
EOF
}
```